# Appium2, not able to identify android element after scrolling down on the mobile screen

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-java, appium-inspector

Description: I'm using appium version2.0 and appium inspector for identifying the elements.
After starting a session in inspector, when I scroll down in my specific mobile application , and try to inspect the elements after scrolling down, not able to select any specific element to be identified, instead the whole screen is getting selected .
Capabilities used :AutomationName- uiAutomator2

Is there any solution to this or is this related to the API lvl as when I'm using the same application on API 26 level emulator, then able to inspect all the elements after scrolling down but If I upgrade to any API level more than 26, say 28 or 30 or 32, then getting this issue.